# Llamar a un .storyboard desde un boton en XCODE 11

Tags: swift, xcode

estoy intentado llamar a un Storyboard desde un boton. 
Tengo un main.storyboard y desde ahí quiero llamar al menu.storyboard.

El código que estoy usando es: Este es mi botón

```
    @IBAction func btnShowSlideNews(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let resultVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "MenuUser")as! MenuUser
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultVC, animated: true)    
   }
```

Detalle del error: 
2019-10-18 12:01:02.962435-0500 Aplicacion Test[5278:78685] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'MenuUser''

Me pueden ayudar por favor. Me muestra error de SIGBART

Comment: Trata de crear de nuevo la conexión al botón a la clase desde el Storyboard

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de errores (SIGBART) se producen porque hay un enlace roto o no creado donde se esperaba.
Si quieres presentar menu.storyboard deberías definir “menu” como nombre del storyboard. Así:

```
@IBAction func btnShowSlideNews(_ sender: Any) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "menu", bundle: nil)
  let resultVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuUser")as! MenuUser
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resultVC, animated: true)
}
```

Puede ser también que en la última línea de la acción, en la que presentas el otro storyboard, navigationController esté devolviendo nil. Revísalo después de cambiar el código como te indiqué. Si sigues experimentando el error o tienes cualquier duda deja un comentario y te intentaré ayudar como pueda.